# CBCentralManagerDelegate not gets call in NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I Create a class that inherit from `NSObject` and also add `delegate` method. In my class I want to use CBCentralManager and its delegate method. But the delegate method doesn't get call. Here is my code -

This is VZBluetooth.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@protocol BluetoothDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)getBluetoothStatus:(NSString*)status;

@end

@interface VZBluetooth : NSObject<CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<BluetoothDelegate> delegate;
-(void)callBluetooth;

@end
```

For VZBluetooth.m

```
@implementation VZBluetooth
{
    NSString *status;
    CBCentralManager *ce;

}
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

-(void)callBluetooth
{
    ce = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Bluetooth Delegate

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{

    if(central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        if ([central respondsToSelector:@selector(scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:)]) {
            status = CASE_STATUS_PASS;
        }
        else{
            status = CASE_STATUS_FAIL;
        }

    }
    else{
        status = CASE_STATUS_FAIL;
    }

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getBluetoothStatus:)]) {
        [self.delegate getBluetoothStatus:status];
    }
}
```

My call -

```
VZBluetooth *blu = [[VZBluetooth alloc]init];
[blu callBluetooth];
blu.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating your `VZBluetooth` instance as a local variable - so as soon as that function exits it will be released. This will almost certainly be before the Bluetooth functions are initialised and get a chance to call a delegate method.

You need to store the instance on a `strong` property in your calling class.

A couple of other suggestions, your `delegate` property in `VZBluetooth` should be `weak` rather than `strong` to prevent retain cycles and you can simplify the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` method considerably -

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{

    status=CASE_STATUS_FAIL;

    if(central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        if ([central respondsToSelector:@selector(scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:)]) {
            status = CASE_STATUS_PASS;
        }
    }
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getBluetoothStatus:)]) {
        [self.delegate getBluetoothStatus:status];
    }
}
```